# phpspreadsheet conditional format column A if value of column B is less than 700

Tags: php, laravel, conditional-formatting, phpspreadsheet, maatwebsite-excel

Currently, I am exporting an excel sheet using maatwebsite 3.1 export in laravel 5.6.
I am using phpspreadsheet concepts for conditional formatting

```
$conditional_fico = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional();
$conditional_fico->setConditionType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional::CONDITION_CELLIS)
->setOperatorType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Conditional::OPERATOR_LESSTHAN)
                            ->addCondition('700');
$conditional_fico->getStyle()->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_RED);
$conditionalStyles = $event->sheet->getStyle('G:G')->getConditionalStyles();
$conditionalStyles[] = $conditional_fico;
$event->sheet->getStyle('G:G')->setConditionalStyles($conditionalStyles);
```

Now i want to Change the color of A:A if respective G:G is less than 700.
Example :

make A1 red if G1 < 700;
make A2 red if G2 <700 and so on.

Please share the corresponding conditional formatting rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out,

```
  $styleArray = array(
            'font'  => array(
              //  'bold'  => true,
                'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000'),
            ));

   $highestRow = $event->sheet->getHighestRow();
   $highestColumn = $event->sheet->getHighestColumn(); 
   $highestColumnIndex = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); 
  for ($row = 3; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
            $slaHours = $event->sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getValue();
            if( $slaHours < 700) {    
            $event->sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getStyle()->applyFromArray($styleArray);
       }
   }
```